# Integration question does this substitution work?

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}dx$$

I'm a little lost here do i let $u = 3-x$, so that $du/dx = 1$, $du=dx$

$$\int_0^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du = u^{-\frac{1}{2}} du$$

$$  \left[\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}} u^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]_0^3 = \left[2(3-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]_0^3$$

$$  = 2\sqrt{0}-2\sqrt{3} = -2\sqrt{3}$$

hi sorry i meant 3-x

Comment: If $u=3-x$ then $du/dx\ne 1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$u=3-x$, $dx=-du$, and as $x$ goes from $0$ to $3$, then $u$ goes from $3$ to $0$, so
$$
\int_0^3 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3-x}} = \int_3^0\frac{-du}{\sqrt{u}} = \int_0^3\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} = \left. 2\sqrt{u} \vphantom{\frac 1 1}\ \right|_0^3 = 2\sqrt{3}.
$$

Comment: So.. what to do?

Comment: hi sorry i meant 3-x

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute $u = 3-x$, $du = -dx$. The bounds change as well so $x =0$ means $u=3$ and $x=3$ means $u=0$

$$\int_0^3 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3-x}} = \int_3^0 \frac{-du}{\sqrt{u}} = \int_0^3 \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} = \left[ 2\sqrt{u} \right]_0^3 = 2(\sqrt{3} - 0) = 2\sqrt{3} $$

Answer (score 0):

The integral is undefined at 3.  We must use an improper integral.

$$
\int_0^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}} dx = \lim_{x \to 3^-}\int_0^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}} dx
$$

using a u substitution where u = 3 - x, then du = -dx which gives the following:

$$
\int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{u}}du = -2\sqrt{u}
$$

Putting this back in terms of x gives us 
$$ -2\sqrt{3-x}
$$
Thus we get

$$
-2\lim_{x \to 3^-}[\sqrt{3-b} - \sqrt{3-0}] = (-2)(-\sqrt{3}) = 2\sqrt{3}
$$